# Rails element added to a set is not found in the set

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am adding an element to a set and although the element can be found in the set later, the `include?` method returns `false` when I search for it.

```
@used_date_first.add(fe.time.beginning_of_day)
p "#{@used_date_first.include?(fe.time.beginning_of_day)}"
```

prints

```
false
```

The set is declared like this:

```
@used_date_first = Set.new
```

Comment: What is fe defined as?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's an issue with your 'fe' var.

If I do this:

```
x = DateTime.now.beginning_of_day
@used_date_first.add(x)
p "#{@used_date_first.include?(x)}"
```

it prints true